# Databricks SQL Code returning differing dateformats in same notebook

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

When I issue the code

```
select as_of_date from myview
```

I get the following date format yyyyMMdd

[image]

But when I issue the following code - on the same field I get the date format yyyy-MM-dd. However, I want the same format as that for the above select statement i.e yyyyMMdd

```
select as_of_date from myview
where as_of_date = last_day(add_months(current_date(),-1)
```

[image]

Can someone let me know how to retain the dateformat i.e. yyyyMMdd?

I have also tried the following in PySpark

```
%python
df = spark.sql("select as_of_date from myview where date_format(as_of_date, 'yyyyMMdd') = date_format(last_day(add_months(current_date(), -1)), 'yyyyMMdd')")
```

But still getting yyyy-MM-dd

Any thoughts?

A good point was made by a member.
The as_of_date is a string (which I didn't realise)
[image]

I tried the following code, but I'm still getting yyyy-MM-dd
[image]

Comment: What is the data type of field `as_of_date` on the table underlying `myview`? My guess is it not a `date` and therefore, your first query is simply retrieving the string-date; where your second query implicitly casts the string-date to a date to make your where-clause condition work, and then surfaces that casted value since it would be quicker. You could probably just specify the format of the date using `date_format()` in the select portion of your query to ensure the format you want in your output is used:  `SELECT date_format(as_of_date, 'yyyyMMdd') as as_of_date`

Comment: Hi @JNevill, I have just updated the question. You are correct. However, I'm not sure what you're suggesting that I do to get the as_of_date to be yyyyMMdd when I issue the PySpark code?

Comment: Just `df = spark.sql("select date_format(as_of_date, 'yyyyMMdd') as as_of_date from myview
where as_of_date = last_day(add_months(current_date(),-1))")` should do the trick.

Comment: Hi @JNevill, that certainly did the trick when calling just the as_of_date field. However, can you let me know how I could get the same yyyyMMdd when doing a select * using the following ```df = spark.sql("select * from myview where as_of_date = last_day(add_months(current_date(),-1))")```

Comment: Basically, I want to include the as_of_date as yyyyMMdd when selecting all fields.

Comment: Someone suggested the following, but it didn't work ```df = spark.sql("select * from myview where date_format(as_of_date, 'yyyyMMdd') = date_format(last_day(add_months(current_date(), -1)), 'yyyyMMdd')")```

Comment: Hi @JNevill, any thoughts on why the still gives me yyyy-MM-dd?

Comment: I’m curious as to why the following won’t give me yyyyMMdd df = spark.sql("select * from myview where date_format(as_of_date, 'yyyyMMdd') = date_format(last_day(add_months(current_date(), -1)), 'yyyyMMdd')")

Comment: can you please try with : select date_format(to_date(as_of_date,'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyyMMdd') as final_date from mytable1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting the Date format yyyy-DD-mm
when you are using the below query

```py
select as_of_date from myview
where as_of_date = last_day(add_months(current_date(),-1)
```

is due to the fact that, the current_date is a SQL Date function. as you see below.
[image]
To Convert the "as_of_date" column to the desired format, I have  tried the below two approaches

**1st approach:**
I have used Date_format the date_format function is used to format a date or timestamp value into a specific string representation. It allows converting a date or timestamp to a desired output format.

```
%sql
select as_of_date from my_table
where as_of_date =  date_format(last_day(add_months(current_date(),-1)), 'yyyyMMdd')
```

[image]

**2nd approach:**
Here in the 2nd Approach I am using the **date_trunc**. it is used to truncate the **as_of_date** column to the month level. The purpose is to compare the truncated **as_of_date** values with the truncated current date minus one month.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import last_day, add_months, expr
result = spark.sql("""
SELECT as_of_date
FROM my_table
WHERE  date_trunc('MONTH', to_date(as_of_date, 'yyyyMMdd')) =
date_trunc('MONTH', add_months(current_date(), -1))
""")
result.show()
```

[image]

Comment: oh, wow, @DileeprajnarayanThumula, I'm going to check this out in the next 15mins. This looks like the exact thing I need. Thank you

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula, unfortunately it didn't work. I have updated my question with the output :-(

Comment: @Patterson How about using the Date format function which takes 2 arguments.
df = df.withColumn("as_of_date", date_format(last_day(add_months(current_date(), -1)), "yyyyMMdd"))

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula, yes that will work. I was just wondering why your other suggestion works for you, but doesn't work for me?

Comment: @Patterson Here is my 
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, date_format
data = [
    ('2023-06-01',),
    ('2023-06-15',),
    ('2023-05-31',),
    ('2023-04-30',),
    ('2023-03-01',)
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['as_of_date'])
df = df.withColumn('as_of_date', col('as_of_date').cast('string'))

df = df.withColumn('as_of_date', date_format(col('as_of_date'), 'yyyyMMdd'))
df.createOrReplaceTempView('my_table')
df.show()
 where explicitly making date format to string
Then I am using the
from pyspark.sql.functions import last_day, add_months, expr

Comment: result = spark.sql("""
    SELECT as_of_date
    FROM my_table
    WHERE date_trunc('MONTH', to_date(as_of_date, 'yyyyMMdd')) =
          date_trunc('MONTH', add_months(current_date(), -1))
""")

result.show()